# Would displaying PHP Exception Message be a security risk?

Tags: php, security, laravel, exception, laravel-5.1

I want to set a custom message to be displayed to the user when I throw an error in Laravel 5.1. For example, in a controller I might have:

```
if(!has_access()){
    abort('401', 'please contact support to gain access to this item.');
}
```

Then my custom error page I would display the error with:

```
$exception->getMessage();
```

However, what if there was a SQL error or other event? Wouldn't that also set the Exception Message which I would be unknowingly outputting on my error page?

The [PHP docs for getMessage()](http://php.net/manual/en/throwable.getmessage.php) don't go into much detail about this.

How can I set a specific exception message without introducing any security risk?

Comment: I don't know about laravel but all the frameworks that I have used include an `HttpException` class (which is derived from `Exception`) and the catch block only catches exceptions of that class `catch(HttpException $e)`. So, I am guessing it is true for Laravel too because it has kind of become a general practice for frameworks to have that

Comment: Potentially yes, because it might display security information such as user login details depending on the exception.... but you shouldn't be displaying the stack trace in a production environment anyway, disable your app debug setting

Comment: That's true. I just replied based on OP's specific function call `$exception->getMessage()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, what if there was a SQL error or other event? Wouldn't that also set the Exception Message which I would be unknowingly outputting on my error page?

**Potentially, yes.** PHP makes no guarantees that the contents of exception messages will be "safe" to display to users, and it's quite likely that some classes will throw exceptions which include sensitive information in the message.

If you want to use exceptions to display errors to users, use a specific subclass of `Exception` for those exceptions, and only print the message if the exception was an instance of that subclass, *e.g.*

```
class UserVisibleException extends Exception {
    // You don't need any code in here, but you could add a custom constructor
    // if you wanted to.
}

// Then, in your abort() function...
throw new UserVisibleException($message);

// Then, in your exception handler...
if ($exc instanceof UserVisibleException) {
    print $exc->getMessage();
} else {
    print "An internal error occurred.";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you access your `app.php` file:

```
  'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),
```

In your production env, set this to false. This would make sure that no debug errors would be displayed in the production environment.

Once this is set, you can respond to normal exceptions through your controller. Anything else, laravel wouldn't display the error page.

Comment: Perhaps I am doing something wrong, but when I set `APP_DEBUG` to false and then change my DB config to use an incorrect SQL password, `$exception->getMessage()` returns:  `The details are: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` which is exactly the type of error I don't want users to see.

Comment: If you turn on the debug and try to access any page that needs connection with database, and if the password if incorrect, it would display the exception to the end user. But in this case, since you turned off the debug mode, the default message would be `Something went wrong`. Laravel would hide the previous database related error message. This would prevent your databse information being displayed to the user. In your example, you are explicitly trying to access the exception and displaying it.

Comment: Right. I am overriding the "something went wrong" error page and am using my own custom error pages (that include the error message). My hope was that I could suppress the system messages and just display the ones I manually set.

Comment: So in this case, you should check for the type of exception and call the corresponding page: for example: if you can't find a user, call `abort(404)`, any payment related error, call `abort(501)`,...

Comment: Yes, I want to call abort(401) but I also want to pass a dynamic message to the user explaining the exact cause.

Comment: If you are worried about specific error type, for example, database information, you should check the error type and then call abort method. In this way, you wouldn't be passing any secure data to the user view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

$e->getMessage() can potentially reveal more information about your code IF you use it in a similar way:

```
try {
    $executeSomethingHereForWhichYouExpectAnException();  
// Basic \Exception that reports everything  
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}
```

even with `'debug' => false` in `app.php`. For example if you have an error with your code $error would display it - basically ANY type of error (PHP,MYSQL,ETC);

However, there is a fix - to catch your CustomException messages and prevent typical error displaying if you use it in like so:

```
try {
    $executeSomethingHereForWhichYouExpectAnException();
// Our custom exception that throws only the messages we want
} catch (\CustomException $e) {
    // Would contain only 'my_custom_message_here'
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}
```

What is the difference you may ask - the difference is that instead of \Exception which is the basic error reporting, we use \CustomException class, which you throw from `$executeSomethingHereForWhichYouExpectAnException()` function:

```
executeSomethingHereForWhichYouExpectAnException(){
   if (something) {
     throw new CustomException("my_custom_message_here", 1);
   }
}
```

If you have more exceptions you can include them like so (as of PHP7.1):

```
try {
   something();
} catch(\CustomException | \SecondCustomException $e) {
  // custom exceptions
} catch(\Exception $e) {
  // basic exception containing everything
}
```